# Getter method for Line class

Tags: java

I have two classes: `Point` class and `LineSub` which `extends` `Point`

Here is the constructor for the first class
The first class also has the `getters` and `setters` for the private vars

```
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public Point(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
```

Here is the second class:

```
public class LineSub extends Point {

    Point end;  // It has only the end instance variable.
    public LineSub(Point begin, Point end) {
       super(begin.getX(), begin.getY());
       this.end = end;
    }
}
```

Question: is it possible to write a `getBegin()` method which returns the beginning point?

Comment: Side note: this is a bad class hierarchy. It's obvious that `Line` does not extend `Point`.

Comment: I know this is bad. It is an exercise from here
http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/J3f_OOPExercises.html#zz-2.
I would much prefer using composition, but this is the exercise.

Comment: OK, you know it's bad.  You've got your pick of answers below.  You can return yourself (return this;) because you are a Point, or you can make a new point after calling getX and getY.  Either works.

Comment: I never follow exercise orders when I think they are wrong. I would write the exercise as I see right, even if it would cost me points (which it mostly didn't, in my case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public Point getBegin() {
return new Point(super.getX(), super.getY());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to write a getter method that would return a `Point` for the starting point (from the `Point` class), but it's not a good design.

What I would do is reconsider your design.  Is a `LineSub` a `Point`?  No, a `LineSub` consists of 2 `Point`s, the start and the end.

Instead of subclassing `Point`, I would create a `Line` class that doesn't extend `Point` with two member variables, each of which would be a `Point`.

```
public class Line {
    private Point begin;
    private Point end;

    public Line(Point begin, Point end) {
       this.begin = begin;
       this.end = end;
    }
}
```

Then you can write two getter methods, one for each of the `Point`s.

Comment: This would have been my answer.  A Line is NOT a Point.  They are two different ideas.  Do not extend a Point to make a Line.

Comment: You can, however, consider creating some other super class (maybe `Graphics` or `DimensionalObject` etc.) that both `Line` and `Point` extends.

Comment: @Elist, you could do that, and it might add something to the whole application, but it would not add anything to this specific example.

Comment: Agreed. That's why I have only suggested to consider the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Sort of. What it would consist of though is just this

```
public Point getBegin(){
    return this;
}
```

Your `LineSub` method doesn't just have a reference to the begin `Point`. It is the begin `Point`.

Since you inherit from `Point`, all of the public methods are fields are accessible to anyone who has a reference to you implementation and, because of the way you're implementing it, that reference is what you consider the beginning point.

Note that this is almost certainly the wrong way to implement this, and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25854942/2499035) is probably what you should use. I'll leave this answer though, because it doesn't require changing your class's implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You code should look like this...

```
public class LineSub {
    Point begin;
    Point end;
    public LineSub(Point begin, Point end) {
       this.end = end;
       this.begin = begin;
    }
}
```

As pointed out you don't need to exited it point.

Comment: In this design of a `LineSub` containing two `Point`s, why should `LineSub` **extend** `Point`?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, yes; although there are multiple ways:

```
public Point getBegin() {
    return new Point(super.getX(), super.getY());
}
```

Another way is to maintain a `begin` instance in your class:

```
Point end;
Point begin;

public LineSub(Point begin, Point end) {
    this.begin = begin;
    this.end = end;
}

public Point getBegin() {
    return this.begin;
}
```

The second way, you will notice, obviates the need for inheritance. In fact, that brings me to my main point. This is a very strange class hierarchy and I would actively recommend against it. A `Line` is **composed** of two points; it is not *itself* two points.

Answer (score 0):

Since `LineSub` extends `Point` and is essentially using its super to store the begin `Point`, you could just return it:

```
public Point getBegin() {
    return this;
}
```

However, if `Point` is mutable this might be a bad idea, since it will allow callers to modify the `LineSub`'s beginning: `myLineSub.getBegin().setX(123);`. A safer way might be to reconstruct the object:

```
 public Point getBegin() {
    return new Point(getX(), getY());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using the getters for `x` and `y`.

```
public Point getBegin() {
    return new Point(getX(), getY());
}
```

However, wouldn't it make more sense to have your line class simply contain two points?

For example:

```
public class Line {
    private Point begin;
    private Point end;

    public Line(Point begin, Point end) {
        this.begin = begin;
        this.end = end;
    }
}
```